# JWT Authentication NodeJS

Tags: node.js, api, jwt

I have a page where user can put their email address, and then if the email is valid it will lead them to the next page.

So I have a third-party API to validate those emails. I'm planning to use JWT on my back-end nodejs to call that API but I think it will require login to authenticate the API call.

Is there a way I can just hardcode the username and pass that will not be able to see on my front end?

I want to securely call my API but I have no login feature on my app to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

You sure can! Check out the [dotenv package on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). This will let you use Environment variables in your NodeJS program.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the Form that has email address input is just made of HTML at JS.

Comment: I mean * HTML and JS